# git rev-list in Jenkins pulling old package from ubuntu

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins job fails with below error

```
git rev-list 5aa70b804fda336307e70c5de16a0a3551af15db # timeout=10
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main unattended-upgrades all 0.82.1ubuntu2.4
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

I can see 2.5 is the latest package. How can this be corrected so that 2.5 package gets pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are some lines in between and an `apt-get install` is executed.

Usually, you should run `apt-get update` to update package indices first.

This is totally unrelated to Jenkins, but a "problem" with Debian/Ubuntu itself.